# Incorporating MongoDB views into Node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mean-stack

In MongoDB v3.4, [views](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/views/) were added as a feature. However, I haven't been able to find any resources for how'd I'd use a view I created in a Node.js application. How would I go about doing this, specifically for an aggregation view?

Comment: So you created a view via Node.js application, and you would like to access the view via the application ?

Answer (score 11):

I also found this to be unclear. Confusingly, you need to use [db.createCollection](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Db.html#createCollection), unlike the `createView` command in the MongoDB shell. For example:

```js
db.createCollection('myView', {
  viewOn: 'myCollection',
  pipeline: [],
});
```

Where `pipeline` is an [Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/). You can then access your View in the same way as a collection:

```js
db.collection('myView').find();
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it as @dcr24 decribed. Here's the complete code

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');
import DB_CONFIG from '../../server/constants/database'
/*
 * Requires the MongoDB Node.js Driver
 * https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native
 */

const agg = [
    {
        '$group': {
            '_id': '$entityGroupId',
            'totalVisits': {
                '$sum': '$visits'
            }
        }
    }, {
        '$sort': {
            'totalVisits': -1
        }
    }, {
        '$lookup': {
            'from': 'entities',
            'localField': '_id',
            'foreignField': 'entityGroupId',
            'as': 'entityGroup'
        }
    }
];

MongoClient.connect(
    DB_CONFIG.URL,
    {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true},
    async function (connectErr, client) {
        assert.equal(null, connectErr);
        const db = client.db('weally');
        // db.createView("entityGroupByVisits", 'complaintvisitcounts', agg)
        await db.createCollection('entityGroupByVisits', {
            viewOn: 'complaintvisitcounts',
            pipeline: agg,
        });
        client.close();
    });
```